# C# equivalent of Delphi's DisableControls/EnableControls

Tags: c#, delphi, dataset

What is the C# equivalent of Delphi's `DisableControls`/`EnableControls` methods (used to disable updating of databound controls while iterating through the underlying dataset)? I have googled for half an hour and did not find an answer...

I have a  list box and a rich edit box bound to a binding source, but I need to do an operation that iterates through the entire dataset, and both controls get updated as I move through the underlying dataset. In Delphi this is easy enough: enclose the block that does the iteration between `DisableControls` and `EnableControls`. I can't find the C#/.NET equivalent, and I have looked really hard!

Comment: What are you using? WinForms or WPF?

Comment: have you tried setting the `RaiseListChangedEvents` property of your bindingsource to `false`?

Answer (score 2):

IIRC, setting `Enabled` to `false` does not prevent the controls from reacting to data changes in WinForms.

Collection-bound controls like the `ListBox` typically have methods `BeginUpdate()` and `EndUpdate()` which temporarily disable visual updates.

Also, the property mentioned by DarkSquirrel might be worth a look

Answer (score 1):

I don't have access to Visual Studio right now, so I can't test this, but look through the methods for the control instance. Code such as:

```
// set the Enabled property of 
// the controls to False; this should
// disable the controls for user access

listBox.Enabled = False;  
richEditBox.Enabled = False;  

// perform iteration  
// and other operations

// set the Enabled property back 
// to True  

listBox.Enabled = True;  
richEditBox.Enabled = True;
```

The exact name of the property may differ slightly, but I'm pretty sure that this is what it is.

Comment: You can also disable entire form by doing `this.Enabled = false`, or even put the controls in a `GroupBox`, then `this.myGroupBox.Enabled = false` will disable all controls inside that Group box; edit: assuming you're in the form code, not an external method

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using WinForms, in that case you can try using the methods [SuspendLayout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.suspendlayout.aspx)/[ResumeLayout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.resumelayout.aspx).

Code sample from MSDN:

```
private void AddButtons()
{
   // Suspend the form layout and add two buttons.
   this.SuspendLayout();
   Button buttonOK = new Button();
   buttonOK.Location = new Point(10, 10);
   buttonOK.Size = new Size(75, 25);
   buttonOK.Text = "OK";

   Button buttonCancel = new Button();
   buttonCancel.Location = new Point(90, 10);
   buttonCancel.Size = new Size(75, 25);
   buttonCancel.Text = "Cancel";

   this.Controls.AddRange(new Control[]{buttonOK, buttonCancel});
   this.ResumeLayout();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So far I know, you don't need to Disiable/EnableControls in C#, since this type of DataSet doesn't work with a current cursor, like Delphi TDataSets.